# Lpad with zero's in vbscript

Tags: string, vbscript

I'm trying to pad a string with 0's to the left.The length of the output string should be 7.
Here's my code :

```
inputstr = "38"
in = string(7 - Len(inputStr),0) & inputStr
msgbox in
```

I'm getting error Expected Statement
Please help me
Thank You

Answer (score 27):

The following code will run 5% faster:

```
inputStr = "38"
result = Right("0000000" & inputStr, 7)

msgbox result
```

Comment: But risks truncating and hardcodes width and filler.

Comment: I just used a length provided in the question above.

Comment: Is a great one-liner answer to the question and intuitively correct... exactly what I needed for this answer -- not a function definition, but something simple, /fastest possible/, and intuitive that I could just drop into my (>31-bit unsigned Hex function) code.  Thanks Andrej.

Answer (score 18):

This function will left-pad an input value to the given number of characters using the given padding character without truncating the input value:

```
Function LPad(s, l, c)
  Dim n : n = 0
  If l > Len(s) Then n = l - Len(s)
  LPad = String(n, c) & s
End Function
```

Output:

```
>>> WScript.Echo LPad(12345, 7, "0")
0012345
>>> WScript.Echo LPad(12345, 3, "0")
12345
```

Answer (score 6):

`in` is a reserved word so can't be used as a variable name and you must pass a string `"0"` not an integer `0`, so:

```
inputStr = "38"
result = string(7 - Len(inputStr), "0") & inputStr

msgbox result
```

Comment: This will still fail if `inputStr` is longer than 7 characters, though.

Answer (score 1):

Function:

```
Private Function LPad (str, pad, length)
    LPad = String(length - Len(str), pad) & str
End Function
```

Use:

```
LPad(12345, "0", 7)
```