# "Do" not recognised at start of loop in VBScript

Tags: loops, vbscript, nested-loops

So, I'm doing this watch program. I have a loop that I use to continuously update time. But for some reason, the system doesn't recognise the `Do` at start of loop. It is in a while loop, if that changes anything. I also put a `On Error Resume Next` but still get error message. Is this linked? Help would be greatly appreciated. Here's source code:

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "about:blank"

While ie.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend

    ie.ToolBar   = False
    ie.StatusBar = False
    ie.Width     = 200
    ie.Height    = 250

    ie.document.body.innerHTML = "<p id='msg'>0</p>"

    Set style = ie.document.CreateStyleSheet
    style.AddRule "p", "text-align: center;"

    ie.Visible = True

    Do
        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LocalTime")

        If objItem.DayOfWeek = 1 Then
            day_name = "Monday"
        Else If objItem.DayOfWeek = 2 Then
            day_name = "Tuesday"
        Else If objItem.DayOfWeek = 3 Then
            day_name = "Wednesday"
        Else If objItem.DayOfWeek = 4 Then
            day_name = "Thursday"
        Else If objItem.DayOfWeek = 5 Then
            day_name = "Friday"
        Else If objItem.DayOfWeek = 6 Then
            day_name = "Saturday"
        Else
            day_name = "Sunday"
        End If

        For Each objItem In colItems
            ie.document.getElementById("msg").innerText = "Date:" & vbCrLf & day_name & vbCrLf & objItem.Day & "/" & objItem.Month & "/" & objItem.Year & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Time:" & vbCrLf & objItem.Hour & " : " & objItem.Minute & " : " & objItem.Second
        Next
    Loop

While End
```

Comment: `While End` at the end seems suspicious. You indentation suggests you think you have started a loop at the first `While` statement, but that is not the case. The whole loop is written in a single line there.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you have an extra `Wend` on your outer [`While` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/661sy9w2(v=vs.84)) so the `While End` expects a `Do` *(`While End` is not valid syntax in VBScript)*.

Remove `Wend` from this line;

```
While ie.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100
```

and change `While End` to `Wend`.

Once that issue is fixed you will have another problem as your inner [`Do` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/57ykwk20(v=vs.84)) loop has no way to exit and will continue infinitely unless you supply a condition that will allow it to exit either by specifying `While` or `Until` or by using `Exit Do`.

#### Summary

This might not be what you want but it will stop that specific error. The problem is without guessing what your intention was it is difficult to refactor the code without changing your intent *(but it looks like [@Hackoo has done it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62343232/692942))*. Would recommend you take a look at the links provided to the [VBScript documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/t0aew7h6(v=vs.84)) that details how the `While` and `Do` loops should be used.

Answer (score 2):

***Note :*** You have some syntax mistakes here :
You should write `ElseIf` instead of `Else If`

And in the last line `While End` to `Wend`

In your question you want to continuously update the time; so you can do it with `Do ..Loop` statement with a Timeout of 1 second inside with `Wscript.sleep 1000`

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "about:blank"

While IE.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
On Error Resume Next
    IE.ToolBar   = False
    IE.StatusBar = False
    IE.Resizable = False
    IE.Width     = 200
    IE.Height    = 165
    REM Here You can add a title to your window if you like
    IE.Document.title = "My Title goes here"
    IE.document.body.innerHTML = "<p id='msg'></p>"
    Set style = IE.document.CreateStyleSheet
    style.AddRule "p", "text-align: center;"
    REM --------------------------------------------------------------
    REM Just for testing i added those two lines
    style.AddRule "p", "font-family:times new roman;font-weight:bold;"
    style.AddRule "p", "background-color:lightblue;"
    REM --------------------------------------------------------------
    IE.Visible = True
Do
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LocalTime")
    For Each objItem In colItems
        If objItem.DayOfWeek = 1 Then
        day_name = "Monday"
        ElseIf objItem.DayOfWeek = 2 Then
        day_name = "Tuesday"
        ElseIf objItem.DayOfWeek = 3 Then
        day_name = "Wednesday"
        ElseIf objItem.DayOfWeek = 4 Then
        day_name = "Thursday"
        ElseIf objItem.DayOfWeek = 5 Then
        day_name = "Friday"
        ElseIf objItem.DayOfWeek = 6 Then
        day_name = "Saturday"
        Else
        day_name = "Sunday"
        End If
        IE.document.getElementById("msg").innerText = "Date:" & vbCrLf &_
        day_name & vbCrLf &_
        LPad(objItem.Day,2,"0") & "/" & LPad(objItem.Month,2,"0") & "/" & objItem.Year & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &_
        "Time:" & vbCrLf &_
        LPad(objItem.Hour,2,"0") & " : " & LPad(objItem.Minute,2,"0") & " : " & LPad(objItem.Second,2,"0")
    Next
    Wscript.sleep 1000
    If Err Then 'user clicked red X (or alt-F4) to close IE window
        IE.Quit
        Set IE = Nothing
        wscript.quit
    End if
Loop
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM This function will left-pad an input value to the given number of characters
REM using the given padding character without truncating the input value:
REM Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151811/lpad-with-zeros-in-vbscript
REM Written by Ansgar Wiechers
Function LPad(s, l, c)
  Dim n : n = 0
  If l > Len(s) Then n = l - Len(s)
  LPad = String(n, c) & s
End Function
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```